# How to prove inequality on quadratic form and orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

This is from a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1114v4.pdf) I'm reading. I don't know how to prove it.

---

- Assume that $\mathbf A$ is an $n\times n$ [positive semi-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix) matrix which has $k$ non-zero eigenvalues. We can assume that all positive eigenvalues are larger than some positive constants $b$ and $b'$. The remaining $n-k$ eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$ are zeros.
- Let $\mathbf P$ be the orthogonal projection onto the image of $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf Q$ is the projection onto its kernel, so that $\mathbf P + \mathbf Q = \mathbf I$.

**Question 1:** The paper says 'it is easy' but I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone explain it?

As $\mathbf P (\mathbf A - b'\mathbf I)^{-1} \mathbf P \succeq \mathbf 0$ and
$\mathbf P (\mathbf A - b\mathbf I)^{-1} \mathbf P \succeq \mathbf 0$, it is *easy* to check that
$$ (b-b')\mathbf P (\mathbf A - b'\mathbf I)^{-2}\mathbf P \preceq
\mathbf P (\mathbf A - b\mathbf I)^{-1} \mathbf P - 
\mathbf P (\mathbf A - b'\mathbf I)^{-1} \mathbf P$$

---

**Question 2:** The paper also mentioned this equation, which I don't know how to prove:

$$tr\left(\mathbf L^T \mathbf Q(\mathbf A - b'\mathbf I)^{-2}\mathbf Q \mathbf L\right)=\frac{||\mathbf Q\mathbf L||_F^2}{b'^2}$$

Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper states that $b' = b - \delta$. I couldn't find what $\delta$ is and I don't feel like reading the whole paper word-by-word, but I think it's safe to assume that $\delta > 0$, so $b > b'$. In that case,
$$A - b {\rm I} \preceq A - b' {\rm I},$$
so
$$(A - b {\rm I})^{-1} \succeq (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1},$$
i.e.,
$$(A - b {\rm I})^{-1} (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1} \succeq (A - b' {\rm I})^{-2}.$$

Now,
\begin{align}
P (A - b {\rm I})^{-1} P &- P (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1} P = P ((A - b {\rm I})^{-1} - (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1}) P \\
&= P ((A - b {\rm I})^{-1} (A - b' {\rm I}) (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1} - (A - b {\rm I})^{-1} (A - b {\rm I}) (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1}) P \\
&= P (A - b {\rm I})^{-1} ((A - b' {\rm I}) - (A - b {\rm I})) (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1} P \\
&= P (A - b {\rm I})^{-1} (A - b' {\rm I} - A + b {\rm I}) (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1} P \\
&= (b-b') P (A - b {\rm I})^{-1} (A - b' {\rm I})^{-1} P \\
&\succeq (b-b') P(A - b' {\rm I})^{-2} P.
\end{align}

As for your second question, note that $(A - b'I)^{-1} = p(A - b'I)$ for some polynomial $p$ (see Horn, Johnson, "Matrix analysis", 2nd ed., Corollary 2.4.3.4). Using the fact that $Q$ is a projector on kernel, i.e., $AQ = 0$,

\begin{align}
(A - b'I)^{-1} Q &= p(A - b'I) Q = p((A - b'I) Q) = p(AQ - b'Q) = p(-b'Q) \\
&= p(-b'{\rm I})Q = -(b')^{-1} Q.
\end{align}
Obviously, from this we have
$$(A - b'I)^{-2} Q = (A - b'I)^{-1} (A - b'I)^{-1} Q = -(b')^{-1} (A - b'I)^{-1} Q = (b')^{-2} Q.$$
Also, since $Q$ is a projector, it is symmetric, so $L^TQ = (Q^TL)^T = (QL)^T$.

Using all this,
$$\mathop{\rm tr}\left( L^T Q (A - b'I)^{-2} QL \right) = (b')^{-2} \mathop{\rm tr} (L^T Q QL) = (b')^{-2} \mathop{\rm tr} ((QL)^T(QL)) = \frac{\|QL\|_F^2}{(b')^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

1. Since $A$ is positive definite, $A=U(D\oplus 0)U^\ast$ for some unitary matrix $U$ and some $k\times k$ positive diagonal matrix $D$. Then $P=U(I_k\oplus0)U^\ast,\ Q=U(0\oplus I_{n-k})U^\ast$ and the given inequality is equivalent to
   $$
   (b-b')(D - b'I_k)^{-2} \preceq (D - bI_k)^{-1} - (D - b'I_k)^{-1}.
   $$
   That is, for each nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$,
   \begin{align*}
   &(b-b')(\lambda - b')^{-2} \le (\lambda - b)^{-1} - (\lambda - b')^{-1}\\
   \Leftrightarrow&(b-b')(\lambda-b) \le (\lambda-b')^2 - (\lambda-b')(\lambda-b)\\
   \Leftrightarrow&(b-b')(\lambda-b) \le (\lambda-b')(b-b')\\
   \Leftrightarrow&0 \le (b-b')^2,
   \end{align*}
   where the last inequality is obviously true.
2. Presumably $L$ is a real matrix. We have $Q=U(0\oplus I_{n-k})U^\ast$. Therefore
   \begin{align*}
   \operatorname{tr}\left(L^T Q(A - b'I)^{-2}Q L\right)
   &=\operatorname{tr}\left(L^T U(0\oplus b'^{-2}I_{n-k})U^\ast L\right)\\
   &=b'^{-2}\operatorname{tr}\left(L^T U(0\oplus I_{n-k})U^\ast L\right)\\
   &= b'^{-2}\operatorname{tr}\left(L^T Q^2 L\right)\\
   &=\frac{\|QL\|_F^2}{b'^2}
   \end{align*}